# Understanding Firebase Storage tokens

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to understand how tokens work in Firebase Storage.

Whenever my web app uploads an image to FS it adds a token to its public url. The problem is whenever you upload that same image file to another part of the web app, it seems like you don't get another file, but a different token for the file url that was already uploaded, thus rendering a 403 error for the previous registered image display.

Is there a way to solve this?

Example:

```
storageRef.put(picture.jpg);
uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL 
// returns something like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your-app>/o/picture.jpg?alt=media&token=09cb2927-4706-4e36-95ae-2515c68b0d6e
```

That url is then displayed somewhere inside an img src.

```
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your-app>/o/picture.jpg?alt=media&token=09cb2927-4706-4e36-95ae-2515c68b0d6e">
```

If the user repeats the process and uploads the same picture.jpg in another section of the app, instead of getting a brand new copy in Firebase Storage, the file is overwritten with an URL ending with a new token; say 12345.

So:

```
 <img src="https://...picture.jpg?alt=media&token=12345"> // New upload renders fine
 <img src="https://...picture.jpg?alt=media&token=09cb2927-4706..."> // But old upload breaks because of wrong url
```

Comment: Use local caching of images

Comment: This is a web app, each image needs its own url even if the file is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's mobile app

Comment: My bad for not pointing that out. Edited.

Comment: What type of token are you referring to? Can you add the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That typically clarifies a lot and allows us to help you more efficiently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done.

Comment: @cerealex I'm facing this problem now. Did you ever find a working solution? The accepted answer doesn't really help. It links to an outdated version of `getDownloadURL`. But that doesn't solve the problem because all it does is give you the new URL link with the new token. The old URL and old token are still invalidated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Tokens are unique for a particular version of an upload.  If you overwrite the file with new content, then a new token will be generated with a new unguessable url.

So in other words, tokens are unique for a particular blob -- they are not unique per storage location.  We did this as an increased measure of security to ensure that developers and end users did not accidentally expose data they did not intend.

You can, however, translate the storage location ("gs://mybucket/myfile.png") into a download url using our js SDK.  That way, you can pass around the gs uri if you wish and translate it to a full URL once you want to place it into an image.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#getDownloadURL

Comment: "unguessable url" how secure is this? Can someone brute force his way into the URLs? Thanks!

Comment: @siebmanb it would be impractical to guess the generated tokens. They're quit long and after attempting to download a file a certain amount of times firebase would throttle the caller

Answer (score 6):

For public file upload: If you upload files in **firebase functions** you'll need to call `makePublic()` on the reference object in order to make it accessible without having a valid token.