# Firebase storage url, new file keep same access token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

Duplicate of: [Firebase storage URL keeps changing with new token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094676/firebase-storage-url-keeps-changing-with-new-token/64129850?noredirect=1#comment113447219_64129850)

When a user uploads a profile pic I store this in firebase storage with the file name as the uid.
Lets say the user then goes and makes say 100 posts + 500 comments and then updates their profile image.

Currently I have a trigger which goes and updates the profile image url in all of the post and comment documents. The reason I have to do this is that when the image is changed in storage the access token is changed and this is part of the url so the old url no longer works.

What I want to do is not have the access token change.  If I can do this I can avoid the mass updates that will massively increase my firestore writes.

Is there any way to do this?  or an alternative?

Edit:
Another solution if you don't mind making the file public.
Add this storage rule and you won't have to use a token to access the file.
This will allow read access to "mydir" globally in any subfolder.

```
match /{path=**}/mydir/{doc} {
    allow read: if true;
}
```

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64129850/4159105

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down.

Comment: I think making URL in even number of segment can solve this problem. like  - folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/image.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @Prodigy here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64129850/10222449
I tried this and it works well.
This will save millions of writes.

```html
var storage = firebase.storage();
    var pathReference = storage.ref('users/' + userId + '/avatar.jpg');
    pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
        $("#large-avatar").attr('src', url);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle any errors
    });
```

Comment: How are you getting over the media token when they update the profile picture ?

Comment: I believe that when the picture is updated I just delete the current one and then go through the same process as uploading a new one with the same name.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that as well, and I can't seem to avoid that token. I've set the bucket as public, and initially had the image as {userid}.png but now tried the ../{userid}/avatar.png and then also tried to first delete the original image and upload the new one. Still nothing, i need the new one to have the token or nothing at all. i've sent feedback to Firebase around this.

Comment: I just had a look at my code and while it did work when I tested it I am not yet using it.  I was planning on adding it in the future.  Do you generate a new token when you upload the updated image?  pathReference.getDownloadURL() should return the full url with token.

Comment: Looks like for me it is something to do with caching of some sort somewhere either on device, cdn or some where else. What i ended up having to workaround this is to apply a dummry parameter on the url (?dummy=asdasd). This is not ideal since it works where i  know the profile... but not when I bring back a list of users...etc...

Comment: Interesting.  I will come back and comment if I have similar issues when I implement.  I have had to do this with things before to stop them caching.  Firebase storage has caching settings too I believe.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two options here:

1. You store the profile image URL only once, probably in the user's profile document, and look it up every time it is needed. In return you only have to write it once.
2. You store the profile image URL for every post, in which case you only have to load the post documents and not the profile URL for each. In return you'll have to write the profile URL in each post document, and update it though.

For smaller networks the former is more common, since you're more likely to see multiple posts from the same user, so you amortizing the cost of the extra lookup over multiple posts.

The bigger the network of users, the more interesting the second approach becomes, as you'll care about read performance and simplicity more than the writes you're focusing on right now.

In the end, there's no singular right answer here though. You'll have to decide for yourself what performance and cost profile you want your app to have.

Comment: If I used a 3rd party service to store the users profile image that allowed a static url even if the image changed this would provide a 3rd alternative with no extra reads or writes. e.g. http://someservice/myaccount/uid.jpg