# Generate thumbnails with predictable URLs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm building a Flutter app for which I use the same image in a different size. For performance reason, I would like to fetch this same image in different sizes depending on the display size on the client.

To do that, I would build a system allowing me to generate thumbnails of every uploaded images on firebase storage using cloud function and then use those thumbnails from the client.

On upload, the user would receive the public URL of the source image and could just append the desired size to the URL to fetch a specific thumbnail version (ex.`https://google.api.com/mybucket/myprofilepicture.png` ->  `https://google.api.com/mybucket/myprofilepicture@2x.png`)

However, firebase cloud storage uses a token protection mechanism (ex. `https://google.api.com/mybucket/myprofilepicture.png?alt=media&token=09cb2927-4706-4e36-95ae-2515c68b0d6e`) [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293781/understanding-firebase-storage-tokens) making the public URLs of newly uploaded files unpredictable from the client.

The official thumbnail generation cloud function example solve this by saving the generated URLs into cloud firestore and therefore, requiring another call to be made from the client to fetch the available thumbnails. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Is there a way to generate predictable URLs for thumbnails to avoid the overhead of storing them in a separate DB?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/

Comment: If it's OK for the images to be publicly readable, you can change your Storage Rules to allow for that and skip the `token=XXXX` portion of your example URL.