# Simple concept question: Can you overwrite a public url used in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, url, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

If a user changes their name or profile picture I want to update a JSON object that is stored at a publically available Firebase URL that holds these values. Is this possible in Firebase - basically reusing a URL?

It would stop me from having to update a lot of data in the Firestore collection.

Example:

- The mobile app has reserved public URLs for users profile data i.e. https://firebasestorage_images.mobileapp.com/uid-123456
- Leon, uid is 123456, uploads a new profile to his mobile app,
- Leons old profile picture has been rewritten with his new profile picture located at https://firebasestorage_images.mobileapp.com/uid-123456
- This stops creators of the mobile from updating every single message, post, etc from changing firestore data to match a new profile picture url

Edit: There are no code problems or bugs as I haven't written it. I cant even find it online

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example?

Comment: @AlexMamo Ive updated it. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a structure that is similar to this one:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- profilePhoto: "https://firebasestorage_images.mobileapp.com/uid-123456"
```

To read the URL that is associated with the user account, you only need to know the UID. So it doesn't really matter what does the `profilePhoto` field contain, the path to reading it will always be the same.

If you are looking to always have a unique URL, that's not possible. When you upload a photo to Firebase Storage, a token is generated. So even if you are using the same name, the new photo overwrites the old one, but a new token is generated. Such an URL looks like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your_app.appspot.com/o/photos/leon.jpg?alt=media&token=617c54b9-5d4c-...
```

You cannot use an old token to update new images.

Comment: Yeah the second half of your question is what I want.  Im really looking to "reserve" a URL space - perhaps not reuse a generated one if that changes anything...

Sad to know this isn't possible. I guess I have to hack a solution together going forward

Comment: Knowing that the second part of my answer was what you were looking for, please also check both [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293781/understanding-firebase-storage-tokens). It will help you solve the issue. Give it a try and tell me if it works.